# Why isn't Mathematica outputting the inverse fourier transform of this function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math

I'm brand new to Mathmematica, so please be nice. I don't understand where I'm going wrong. I just need to use the method of inverse fourier transform on this wavefunction to get the momentum-space wavefunction.

**The original wavefunction:**

[image]

**The output, which doesn't seem right**

[image]

Comment: Should be posted in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't even know there was a whole SE site for it. Thanks!

Comment: Mathematica is fiercely case sensitive so it is Pi and E and I, not pi and e and i. Usually the argument to InverseFourierTransform from w (or x) to t doesn't have w and x and t in the expression you want to transform. Seeing if you can correct both those might lead you to a solution.